# react js Jest test should not use <Link> outside <Router> when using <Link to="">

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am writing a react js page where the render html page has the following

```
<p>
  <Link to="/MyPage">My Page</Link>
</p>
```

When I run a jest test, I get the following error

you should not use  outside

I tried using

import { BrowserRouter, Link,  MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

```
<BrowserRouter>
<p>
  <Link to="/MyPage">My Page</Link>
</p>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I also tried  MemoryRouter but the Link no longer works.

The Jest error went away and passed the file but the link no longer works.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps somebody, got this work to work without the error

<Button color="link" size="lg" onClick={event => window.location.href='#/myPage/'}>My Page